# Encrypting web.config connection string - does it use the machine key for the site? Do I encrypt the machine key as well?

Tags: asp.net, iis, encryption, web-config

Looking here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx

They encrypt the `machineKey` in the `web.config` as well as the `ConnectionStrings`.

Is this because, when using a custom `machineKey` per site, it will use the machine key to encrypt the connection string?

Or is the machine key just used for view state encryption? And therefore it's prudent to encrypt it to help protect the application?

Comment: [Explanation on Machine Key in similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759536/asp-net-machinekey-config-section-default-location)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MachineKey` is used only to encrypt/decrypt/validate ASP.NET cookies and anti forgery tokens and it handles mostly USER data related security. `MachineKey` has nothing to do with decrypting configuration values. ASP.NET will not use `MachineKey` to decrypt connection string.

Infact `MachineKey` is as sensitive as connection string, because after obtaining it, someone can easily create an authenticated cookie which will allow them to login to any user. That's why it should be encrypted.

You have to encrypt `MachineKey` by yourself.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and explaining why I should encrypt the `machinekey` as well. If you use the default `machineKey` per app in IIS, is it still obtainable, or does that effectively secure it?

Comment: Default MachineKey is not accessible, I think IIS manages automatically and puts it somewhere, but is that secure or not, I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks - I assume the machine config and other OS level items are harder to get at than a potential `web.config` sitting in a FTP site etc... Thank you again for the clarification, and how a machine key could be used against you!